# How to limit maximum length of Textview in Android, i want to set 10 lines and 100 words

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

How to limit maximum length of TextView and  maximum lines in Android through XML
i want to set 10 lines and 100 words.

Comment: i am new to android programming please help @Andreas

Comment: I did help, I gave you the answers to both your questions.